# custom validation and formatting the response returned from the datadase - BEGINNER

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to `Node.js`. This is a 2 part questions. The full source code is found below.

1.) Before saving to the database I need to validate (for example check **if the password contains 6 characters**, and **if it contains 1 numeric value**) the data inserted by the end user. Where, and how can I do this ?

my workings are illustrated below:

```
module.exports.addUser = function(user, callback) {

    // 
    if (user.email.length < 7 ) {
      // How can I send a JSON formmated error message to the user ?
    }
    User.create(user, callback);
  }
```

2.) If the User successfully adds a user, I am returning that object to the user. With this object returned I also need to return the `STATUS` as `SUCCESS`. How can I do this? (Like the example shown below - Also please note that I am **NOT** returning the password in the JSON)

```
[{
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "User": {
            "_id": "57377e3ec955f8620620b242",
            "name": "yoyo",
            "email": "chris@heytoe.com",
            "__v": 0

        }
    }

]
```

**FULL SOURCE CODE**

APP.jS

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

User = require('./models/user');
  app.post('/my/user',function(req,res){
    var user = req.body;

    User.addUser(user, function(err,users){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        } else {
            res.json(users);
        }
        
    })
});
```

USER.JS <-- in `models/user.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        unique: true
    },

    password:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    nickname:{
        type: String,
        required:false
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        deault: Date.now
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);

module.exports.addUser = function(user, callback) {
    User.create(user, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question:

There are couple of ways. You can check the value before insert it as your code :

```
User = require('./models/user');
  app.post('/my/user',function(req,res){
    var user = req.body;
    if (user.password.length > 6 && user.password.match(/\d+/g)) {
      User.addUser(user, function(err,users){
         if(err){
             throw err;
         } else {
             res.json(users);
         }

      })
    } else { throw err; }
});
```

Or

add your schema validation property. For instance:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: [validatePassword, 'Password is invalid.']
  }
});

var validatePassword = function(value) {
  return (value.length < 6  ||  !value.match(/\d+/g));
};
```

Besides, there is a pre method to call the fnction before save the value. check this [mongoose pre](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

```
schema.pre('save', function(doc, next) {
  if (doc.password.value < 6 || !value.match(/\d+/g)) return next("Invalid");
  next();
});
```

Your second question:

when you send res json, you can add this as object property:

```
res.json({ users: users, status: "SUCCESS" });
```

if you dont want to send password. you can delete propery.

```
delete user['password']
```

then send it, but before send it you might need to copy or clone the object.